# Python & MySQL mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to use `import mysql.connector`  to `SELECT *` from a table with ~1.9million rows in a remote database.

When I run the same query using the mysql cli client everything works just fine so I don't believe the issue is network or serverside. I've tried increasing `connection_timeout` to ridiculous numbers, but I still run into `mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Any ideas what to try next?

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="mysql.prod.example.com",
        user="user",
        password="pass",
        database="db",
        auth_plugin='mysql_native_password',
        connection_timeout=1000000
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor(dictionary=True)

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")

update_list = []

for row in mycursor:
        row_id = row["id"]
        row_ip = row["ip"]
        print("IP: "+row_ip)

        newlist = [row_id,row_ip,"/128"]
        update_list.append(newlist)
```

Comment: error occurs at line `mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")`? Can you post the full version of Traceback ?

Comment: Thanks for looking @JayPeerachai Solved my own problem when I went to edit this post with the exact python version and realized I was on a system that still defaults to python2.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from Python2 to 3 solved my problem.

```
-   #!/usr/bin/python
+   #!/usr/bin/python3
```